# Win 10 - how to interpret powercfg /systempowerreport

Tags: windows-10, sleep, powercfg

Really this question is about fixing sleep on my win 10 box.
But part of that journey is understanding what is generated when i run
`powercfg /SYSTEMPOWERREPORT`

Win 10 Pro
20H2
19042.928

## observations:

- i manually put computer to sleep
- computer appears to go to sleep.

  - screen goes blank.
  - fan can be heard to die.
  - power led on case blinks
  - leds on keyboard and mouse go dark (e.g. num lock led)
- i go away for several hours
- i come back and attempt to wake computer from sleep by pressing power button. (have also tried pressing space bar on keyboard or pressing mouse button)
- computer appears to begin waking up.

  - power button led on case becomes solid.
  - fan spins up
- but computer seems to be stuck.

  - screen continues to be blank.
  - keyboard leds do not light up
- have attempted leaving it in this state for up to an hour, and still no change.
- manually shutdown and power back on by using physical power button on case
- when computer comes back up and i run `powercfg /SYSTEMPOWERREPORT` i get

[image: systemreport]

## Questions:

Lets focus on a small subset of this

- row 14 - I believe this is where i put the computer to sleep manually. yet it says `shutdown` for 17 secs and then on row 15 it goes to `active` for 7h48mins?
  Why doesn't it say sleep on row 14/15?
  If i drill down to rows 14 and 15,there is no detailed os state data.
  What can explain why the power state is "active" when from the outside it physically looks asleep?
- row 17 - i don't understand what bug check is and can't find documentation online about it. Can someone help elaborate what is bugcheck?

What should i be looking at to understand the information in this report so that I can fix my sleep issues?

### What i have tried to fix sleep issue:

- updating display drivers (amd radeon)
- disabling hibernate
- disabling wake timers
- other things i don't remember.

Comment: Try also updating BIOS and Power Drivers to fix the bugcheck.

Comment: just did BIOS. whats power driver? is this like chipset driver? i did that too

Comment: Check the manufacturer support site to see if there is a power driver / power management driver. There may not be. Update if there is one.